# How to implement auto Auto-Complete on Intel App Framework?

Tags: android, jquery, user-interface, autocomplete, appframework

I am working on an Android project with Phonegap and using Intel App Framework for UI as it was said to be a fastest mobile framework.

I have checked the Kitchen Sink demo came with the App framework package for auto-complete implementation. But it had only search bar implementation and No Search filter or Auto-complete implementation option.

I have found Jquery Mobile have a good auto complete and filtering options for the search bar. Is there any way to stick with Intel App Framework and get auto complete and filtering implemented ?

I googled for a solution as well as searched here but there were no solutions provided. Please help me if there is a way to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

Add jquery-ui.js after below node.

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="./ui/appframework.ui.js"></script>
```

Now we can use all ui plugins.